Raw HTTP header parser

The code must produce the desired output

Input
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: scheme://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Sec-WebSocket-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits0.0.0.0:8080

Code
function getHeaders(rawHeaders) {
  const arr = rawHeaders.match(/.+/g).map((line) => line.split(/:\s|\s\/\s/));
  console.log(arr);
  return new Headers(arr);
}

Result
console.log(JSON.stringify([...getHeaders(rawHttpHeaders)], null, 2));
VM550:17 (13) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)]
VM550:21 [
  [
    "accept-encoding",
    "gzip, deflate"
  ],
  [
    "accept-language",
    "en-US,en;q=0.9"
  ],
  [
    "cache-control",
    "no-cache"
  ],
  [
    "connection",
    "Upgrade"
  ],
  [
    "get",
    "HTTP/1.1"
  ],
  [
    "host",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "origin",
    "scheme://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ],
  [
    "pragma",
    "no-cache"
  ],
  [
    "sec-websocket-extensions",
    "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits0.0.0.0:8080"
  ],
  [
    "sec-websocket-key",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ],
  [
    "sec-websocket-version",
    "13"
  ],
  [
    "upgrade",
    "websocket"
  ],
  [
    "user-agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
  ]
]


The code must not error or contain known bugs X
The title should describe what the code does X
The more code you provide the more we can help X

